# Click в canvas по нескольким объектам

Tags: javascript, canvas, click

Помогите сделать так, чтобы клик работал на все объекты Fish.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


var fish = new Image();
fish.src = 'рыба.png';
var backfish = new Image();
backfish.src = 'рыбабэк.png';
var petyx = new Image();
petyx.src = 'petyx.png';
var petyxtwo = new Image();
petyxtwo.src = 'petyx2.png';
var bg = new Image();
bg.src = 'bg.jpg';
var bubble = new Image();
bubble.src = 'пузырь.png';
var bubbletwo = new Image();
bubbletwo.src = 'пузырь2.png';

var xPos = 0;
var yPos = canvas.height/2 - 100;
var score = 0;
var arr = [fish,petyx,backfish,petyxtwo];
var c = 0;

function getRandom(min, max){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }

var Bubble = function (){
    this.size = getRandom(30,80);
    this.x = getRandom(0,canvas.width - this.size);
    this.y = canvas.height;
    this.xSpeed = 0;
    this.ySpeed = -(getRandom(3,8));
    s = getRandom(0,1);
    if (s == 0) this.png = bubble;
    else this.png = bubbletwo;
}
Bubble.prototype.draw = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(this.png,this.x,this.y,this.size,this.size);
}

Bubble.prototype.move = function(){
    this.x += this.xSpeed;
    this.y += this.ySpeed;
}

Bubble.prototype.check = function(){
    if (this.y < -(this.size)) {
        this.y = canvas.height;
        this.x = getRandom(0,canvas.width - this.size);
        s = getRandom(0,1);
        if (s == 0) this.png = bubble;
        else this.png = bubbletwo;
    }
}
function position(){
    n = getRandom(0,1);
    if (n == 0) return -sizeforpos;
    else return canvas.width;
}
var Fisher = function () {
    this.size = getRandom(100,200);
    sizeforpos = this.size;
    this.x = position();

    if(this.x == -this.size) number = getRandom(0,1);
    else number = getRandom(2,3);
    this.riba = arr[number];

    this.y = getRandom(0,canvas.height - this.size);
    this.xSpeed = getRandom(3,11);
    this.ySpeed = 0;
};

Fisher.prototype.draw = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(this.riba,this.x,this.y,this.size,this.size);

} 

Fisher.prototype.move = function(){
    this.x += this.xSpeed;
    this.y += this.ySpeed;
}

Fisher.prototype.check = function () {
    if (this.x > width) {
        this.xSpeed = -this.xSpeed;
        this.riba = arr[getRandom(2,3)];
    }
    else if (this.x < -this.size){
        this.xSpeed = -this.xSpeed;
        this.riba = arr[getRandom(0,1)];
    }
    if (this.x == width || this.x == -this.size) {
        this.size = getRandom(100,200);
        sizeforpos = this.size;
        this.x = position();
        this.xSpeed = getRandom(3,11);
        this.y = getRandom(0,canvas.height - this.size);
        if(this.x == -this.size) {
            number = getRandom(0,1);
            this.riba = arr[number];
        }
        else if (this.x == canvas.width){
            number = getRandom(2,3);
            this.xSpeed = -this.xSpeed;
            this.riba = arr[number];
        }
    }
}      
Fisher.prototype.checkclick = function () {
    X = this.x; // здесь вроде создаю переменные для проверки x,y координат, но клик работает только на одну рыбу.
    SIZE = this.size;
    Y = this.y;
    document.getElementById('mouseX').innerHTML = 'X = ' + this.x + ', SIZE = ' + this.size + ', Y = ' + this.y;

}

function MouseClick (e){
    var x = e.pageX - e.target.offsetLeft;
    var y = e.pageY;
    document.getElementById('mouseX').innerHTML = 'X = ' + X + ', SIZE = ' + SIZE + ', Y = ' + Y;
    document.getElementById('mouseY').innerHTML = 'x = ' + x + ', y = ' + y;
    if (x >=X && x<=X + SIZE && y>=Y && y <= Y + SIZE){
        document.getElementById('mouseY').innerHTML = 'x = ' + x + ', y = ' + y;
        score += 1;
        document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = 'SCORE: ' + score;
    }
    else {
        score -=1;
        if (score < 0){
            document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = 'SCORE: Вы проиграли';
            return false;
        }
        document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = 'SCORE: ' + score;
    }
}
function drawbg(){
    ctx.drawImage(bg,0,0);
}


var Bubbles = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    Bubbles[i] = new Bubble(); 
}


var Fish = [];        
for(var i = 0; i < 15; i++){
            Fish[i] = new Fisher(); 
}

var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;

setInterval(function () {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    ctx.drawImage(bg,0,0);
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){     
                Fish[i].draw();
                Fish[i].move();
                Fish[i].check();
                Fish[i].checkclick();
            } 
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){   
            Bubbles[i].draw();
            Bubbles[i].move();
            Bubbles[i].check();
    }
    ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, width, height);
}, 30);
canvas.addEventListener('click',MouseClick);
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно это написать. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Загрузите картинки куда-нибудь и запишите в свой код полные пути к ним, если хотите получить ответ.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let number;
let score = 0;
const arr = ["green", "red", "blue", "black"];
const Fish = [];
const width = canvas.width;
const height = canvas.height;

const getRandom = (min = 0, max = 1) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

// Надеюсь у вас не возникнет проблем из-за того, что я использовал более удобный синтаксис
class Fisher {
  constructor(){
    this.reset();
  }
  tick(){
    this.move();
    this.check();
    this.checkclick();
    this.draw();
  }
  reset(){
    this.clicked = false;
    this.size = getRandom(30, 60);
    this.x = Math.random() > .5 ? canvas.width : -this.size;

    if(this.x == -this.size) number = getRandom();
    else number = getRandom(2,3);
    this.riba = arr[number];

    this.y = getRandom(0, canvas.height - this.size);
    this.xSpeed = getRandom(2, 7);
    this.ySpeed = 0;
  }
  draw() {
    // ctx.drawImage(this.riba,this.x,this.y,this.size,this.size);
    ctx.fillStyle = this.riba;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x,this.y,this.size,this.size);
  } 
  move(){
    this.x += this.xSpeed;
    this.y += this.ySpeed;
  }
  check(){
    if (this.x > width) {
      this.xSpeed = -this.xSpeed;
      this.riba = arr[getRandom(2,3)];
    } else if (this.x < -this.size) {
      this.xSpeed = -this.xSpeed;
      this.riba = arr[getRandom()];;
    }
    if (this.x == width || this.x == -this.size) {
      this.reset();
    }
  }      
  checkclick() {
    if(this.clicked){
      console.log(`${Fish.indexOf(this)} fish clicked`);
      this.clicked = false;
      this.reset();
    }
  }
}


function MouseClick (e) {
    var x = e.pageX - e.target.offsetLeft;
    var y = e.pageY - e.target.offsetTop;
    
    // Запишем всех рыб попавших под курсор в массив
    const clicked = Fish.filter(fish => x >= fish.x && x <= fish.x + fish.size && y >= fish.y && y <= fish.y + fish.size);
    // Если ни одной не кликнуто
    if(!clicked.length){
        score -=1;
        if (score < 0){
            document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = 'SCORE: Вы проиграли';
            Fish.length = 0;
            return;
        }
    } else {
        // Добавим очки за каждую рыбку
        score += clicked.length;
        // Пометим рыбку кликнутой, для метода checkclick (хотя не понятно зачем он)
        clicked.forEach(fish => fish.clicked = true);
    }
    document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = 'SCORE: ' + score;
}

 
while(Fish.length < 7) Fish.push(new Fisher());

const tick = () => {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  Fish.forEach(fish => fish.tick());
  ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, width, height);
  // Лучше использовать это вместо setInterval. Погуглите.
  requestAnimationFrame(tick);
}
tick();

canvas.addEventListener('click', MouseClick);
```

```html
<div id='score'></div>
<canvas id='myCanvas'></canvas>
```

Было бы очень мило, если бы вы потрудились создать [Минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) для удобства отвечающих.
Я потратил довольно много времени, чтобы просто запустить ваш код.